# Proper contour break

Tags: python, opencv

I want to analyse object geometry in images with the help of contours. This way parameters like angle and distance can be determined:

[image]

But some images look like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am trying to make a contour break in between both objects, problem is that the objects have not a fixed size. They can change their length and shape. As a result the contour break is done at wrong positions, so that no proper analysis is possible. Right now the contour break is coupled with the size of the lower object. This is how a correct break should look like:

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

**Edit:**

Folder with Input Images:
https://ufile.io/v6fqs

Example:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What criteria do you use to decide where the contour should be split/broken? Is it solely based on the contour properties or do you use any features in the underlying image?

Comment: It should be better if you show us the original images (without the binary masks), But I can guess, watershed algorithm could be your solution. If you had color images, fuzzy C-means would be great too.

Comment: if you have the full (connected) contour, compute the distance transform in the whole image. Then compute the average (or median) distance of the blue line pixels to that border. Then compute the maximum distance of the cut-lines to the full contour and test whether it is bigger than some minimum distance and not much lower than the average (expected) distance.

Comment: @dhanushka Right now the break is based on the length of the lower line, which is a vague representation of the object body. This is a very inaccurate approach because the lighting on the objects changes when it moves. This results in less photones caught by the camera. Thus the object looks smaller/larger. It worked with an zylinder object. But this is a spiral. It is too inaccurate.

Comment: @Meisam I added Input images as well as a link to their folder in the **Edit** Section

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the examples and the well framed question.

That's a big issue indeed, even more considering medical imaging. Seems to me that the answer lies in a blob detection and separation method.

A good method for that would be to do some binarization, morphological transforms and search for convexity defects (https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gada4437098113fd8683c932e0567f47ba).

```
convexityDefects =  cv.convexityDefects(contour, convexhull[, convexityDefects] )
```

And I also think this thread can help you as well:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/71691/single-blob-multiple-objects-ideas-on-how-to-separate-objects/